# Filter for direct paths in a data set using R

Tags: r, recursion

I do have the following simple data.frame in R:

```
structure(list(start = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), end = c(2L, 10L, 3L, 
4L), type = c("indirect", "indirect", "indirect", "direct")), .Names= c("start", 
"end", "type"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

The table view is as follows:

```
  start end     type
1     1   2 indirect
2     2  10 indirect
3     2   3 indirect
4     3   4   direct
```

The table is an example for a network. Each row shows a direction from a starting point to an endpoint, e.g., the first row describes the path from "1" to "2".

The column "type" only makes sense with the following piece of additional info: In the example, we are looking for every (sub)path that is part of a predefined "main" path. In the example, the predefined query was "Give me every sub-path that I need in order to get from a **starting point 1** to the **endpoint 4**. All intermediate steps are labelled as "indirect", only the last step that ends with the pre-defined ending node is labelled as "direct".

The task now is to filter for these all relevant steps (sub-paths). In our example, only the following path brings you from 1 to 4:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

However, there is also a "dead end" path:

1 -> 2 -> 10 -> Dead end (no connecting path to 4)

The goal is now to filter the data set for keeping only the rows (= sub paths) that form part of a successful overall path from 1 to 4. Hence, in the current example we would like to keep everything except row 2. The result should look as follows:

```
  start end     type
```

1     1   2 indirect
2     2   3 indirect
3     3   4   direct

What would be an easy way of doing that? Remember that in a more complex scenario we will have to do that in a recursive manner, i.e., there could me more "intermediate" steps between the starting node and the ending node. 
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use libraries like dplyr or data.table; solutions using just base R would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what we have (I slightly expanded example):

```
require(data.table)
target <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
dt <- data.table(start = c(1,2,2,3,2), 
                 end = c(2,10,3,5,5), 
                 type = c("indirect", "indirect", "indirect", "direct", "direct"))
df <- data.frame(start = c(1,2,2,3,2), 
                 end = c(2,10,3,5,5), 
                 type = c("indirect", "indirect", "indirect", "direct", "direct"))
```

Breaking it down to two steps:

Finding sub-paths that belong to the final solution

```
dt[,overlap:=apply(dt[,.(start, end)], 1, function(x) all(x[1]:x[2] %in% target))]
df$overlap <- apply(df[,c("start", "end")], 1, function(x) all(x[1]:x[2] %in% target))
```

Finding out if subpaths add up to total target path

```
coverage <- NULL
#dt
all(unique(as.vector(unlist(apply(dt[overlap == TRUE,.(start, end)], 1, function(x) coverage <- c(coverage, x[1]:x[2]))))) %in% target)
#df
all(unique(as.vector(unlist(apply(df[df$overlap == TRUE,c("start", "end")], 1, function(x) coverage <- c(coverage, x[1]:x[2]))))) %in% target)
```

Output:

```
target
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

dt[overlap == TRUE]
df[df$overlap == TRUE,]

   start end     type overlap
1:     1   2 indirect    TRUE
2:     2   3 indirect    TRUE
3:     3   5   direct    TRUE
4:     2   5   direct    TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this approach! Unfortunately, we have to use base R as we are not allowed to install any additional libraries. I will clarify that in my original posting.

Comment: `data.table` package in this case is just a convenience/personal preference thing (I can't see a reason ever using base df when dt is so much better). For data frames - logic is exactly the same, only thing that changes is some syntax for assignment and subsetting.